# How does strsplit work on fixed elements with the splitter at the end of the string to split?

Tags: r, string, split, strsplit, stringi

I was working on a language parser and I wanted to count certain string elements (say `"</i>"`) in a larger string.  Since the string has been cleansed (`str.trim`), it doesn't have any content after it.  I was getting some weird behavior on `strsplit` as it seems to behave differently if the separator `sep` (called `split` in RTM) is at the beginning or end of the string.

Below is an example:

```
str1 = "<i>hello friend</i>"; 
str2 = paste0(" ",str1);
str3 = paste0(str1, " ");

sep1="<i>";
sep2="</i>";

str = c(str1, str2, str3);  n = length(str);
sep = c(sep1, sep2);        ns = length(sep);

base = matrix("", nrow=n, ncol=ns);
rownames(base) = str; colnames(base) = sep;
for(i in 1:n)
    {
    for(j in 1:ns)
        {
        base[i, j] = paste0(base::strsplit(str[i], sep[j], fixed=TRUE)[[1]], collapse="|");
        }   
    }
base;
    
stringi = matrix("", nrow=n, ncol=ns);
rownames(stringi) = str; colnames(stringi) = sep;
for(i in 1:n)
    {
    for(j in 1:ns)
        {
        stringi[i, j] = paste0(stringi::stri_split_fixed(str[i], sep[j])[[1]], collapse="|");
        }   
    }
stringi;

stopifnot(identical(base,stringi));
```

The output for **base**:

```
> base;
                     <i>                  </i>               
<i>hello friend</i>  "|hello friend</i>"  "<i>hello friend"  
 <i>hello friend</i> " |hello friend</i>" " <i>hello friend" 
<i>hello friend</i>  "|hello friend</i> " "<i>hello friend| "
```

The output for **stringi**:

```
> stringi;
                     <i>                  </i>               
<i>hello friend</i>  "|hello friend</i>"  "<i>hello friend|" 
 <i>hello friend</i> " |hello friend</i>" " <i>hello friend|"
<i>hello friend</i>  "|hello friend</i> " "<i>hello friend| "
```

The **core** difference is ROW=1, COL=2 ...

### Question:  What is `E[strsplit]`?

Is **base** a FEATURE and **stringi** a BUG? Or vice versa?

Should not EOS (end of string) splits behave the same as BOS (beginning of string) splits?

```
> R.version
               _                                
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32               
arch           x86_64                           
os             mingw32                          
crt            ucrt                             
system         x86_64, mingw32                  
status                                          
major          4                                
minor          2.1                              
year           2022                             
month          06                               
day            23                               
svn rev        82513                            
language       R                                
version.string R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
nickname       Funny-Looking Kid
```

and

```
> packageVersion("stringi")
[1] ‘1.7.8’
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would say that the `stringi` behavior is the one at least I'd expect (and there you have the option to discard empty strings by setting `omit_empty = TRUE`).

However, since `base::strsplit` clearly documents the behavior it is also a "feature". From `?strsplit`:

> Note that this means that if there is a match at the beginning of
> a (non-empty) string, the first element of the output is ‘""’, but
> if there is a match at the end of the string, the output is the
> same as [the input] with the match removed.

`stringi` provides a much more configurable interface at the expense of another dependency.

Comment: Nice work digging into the DOCS on this one.  I have written a wrapper function that uses `stringi` with `base` as a fallback.  I __just added__ a FILLER on the end and subtract it off afterwards to get the behavior I was expecting.